# Question about the result of the Thorn function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I recently made a function, not sure if a similar function already exists so I named it thorn (þ), to make it easier to talk about. I do not understand why my þ(x) function does not produce results higher than 9,99%.

**Why does þ(x) give results till 0,099... but not higher?**

Formula written out in case the image is no longer accessible:

```
ΣI   = t(1) = first  (1/3) part of the sequence summed up.
ΣII  = t(2) = second (1/3) part of the sequence summed up.
ΣIII = t(3) = third  (1/3) part of the sequence summed up.

þ(x) = ((ΣIII - ΣII) - ΣI)/ (stop x)Σ(start n=1) ⧺ (n1, n2, n3) = ΔΣ
    
þ(∞) = 0,099…
```

**----------How the function is designed----------**

Imagine you have a sequence (1,2,3), you can say 1 + 2 = 3 or you can say 3 - 1 = 2, and if you like you can even say 3 - 2 = 1. It is therefore quickly discovered that all 1/3 parts of the sequence are open to being calculated with, and produce equal results, for all parts are equally related to one another.

Now imagine that this very same sequence of (1,2,3) is each time extended with three extra numbers, to make the sequence longer and allowing the sequence to still be cut in three equal sizes. So it would go like this:

```
(1,2,3)
(1,2,3,4,5,6)
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
...
```

A sequence can be divided into three tridants, (1/3 parts) and summed up together. To be clear and for everyone to better understand this whole post, I write tridants of a sequence in six different ways: t(1) or ΣI, t(2) or ΣII, and t(3) or ΣIII; it often depends on the emphasis which one I choose.. hope no one minds.. :3

```
Example for finding ΣI, ΣII and ΣIII if x = 4

þ(x)

þ(1)
(1,2,3)
t(1) = 1
t(2) = 2
t(3) = 3

þ(2)
(1,2,3,4,5,6)
t(1) = (1,2) = 3
t(2) = (3,4) = 7
t(3) = (5,6) = 11

þ(3)
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
t(1) = (1,2,3) = 6
t(2) = (4,5,6) = 15
t(3) = (7,8,9) = 24

þ(4)
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
t(1) = (1,2,3,4) = 10
t(2) = (5,6,7,8) = 26
t(3) = (9,10,11,12) = 42

So for þ(4) I would start with:
tridant 1 = ΣI   =  t(1) = (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) = 10
tridant 2 = ΣII  =  t(2) = (5 + 6 + 7 + 8) = 26
tridant 3 = ΣIII =  t(3) = (9 + 10 + 11 + 12) = 42
```

In the shortest sequence like (1,2,3) I can say:

```
(t(3) - t(2) = t(1))   = (3 - 2 = 1)
```

But in a longer sequence like (1... ...12) i cannot say:

```
(t(3) - t(2) = t(1))   because: 42 - 26 ≠ 10
```

Therefore, there is a difference in summing up, called ΔΣ. Every single calculation of each tridant with plus or minus compared to what it should have resulted, results in an equal ΔΣ number.

The þ(x) function creates a percentage of ΔΣ, that together with the whole sequence summed up must result in exactly 100%. Below an example of how I calculate the ΔΣ number, below the example I wrote out how I obtain the percentage of ΔΣ.

```
Full example of the þ(x) function:

x = 4
þ(x)
þ(4)
sequence = (1,2,3) ⧺ (4,5,6) ⧺ (7,8,9) ⧺ (10,11,12)
sequence = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
Σsequemce = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 = 78

t(1) = ΣI    = (1+2+3+4)    = 10
t(2) = ΣII   = (5+6+7+8)    = 26
t(3) = ΣIII  = (9+10+11+12) = 42

Assume that for sequence (1,2,3) you can do:
t(3) - t(2) = t(1)   = 3 - 2 = 1
t(3) - t(1) = t(2)   = 3 - 1 = 2
t(1) + t(2) = t(3)   = 1 + 2 = 3

If trying to do the same for sequence (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12):
t(3) - t(2) = t(1)
42 - 26 ≠ 10
42 - 26 = 16
ΔΣ = 16 - 10 = 6

If repeated for all possibile variations:
42 - 26 = 16 and 16 - 10 = ΔΣ = 6
10 + 26 = 36 and 42 - 36 = ΔΣ = 6
42 - 10 = 32 and 32 - 26 = ΔΣ = 6

(ΔΣ + Σsequence = 100%)
6 + 78 = 84
6 / 84 = 0.071.. ≈ 7,1%
þ(4) = 0.071.. ≈ 7,1%
```

If this process is repeated for infinity one whould reach 0,099 or 9,99%. I made the formulas below to make it easy to plug this into excel and check it out:

**----------How to plug the statistics into excel----------**

Create a column title for n, #, Σ, þ(n), Σ%, þ(n)%, t(1), t(2), and t(3). Make a very long list of n-numbers below one another, plug each formula in and set up the right cell for the n-number inside each formula and drag along to fill in all the empty sheet cells. In excel you can make a graph out the information and see that þ(x) does not produce results higher than 0,099...

I do realize that power numbers and roots seen in graphs often display infinite curve patterns, but I hope that someone can tell me why that happens in this particular way of just not reaching 10%! O.O

```
n = x
# = n3
Σ = ((n*3)^2+(n*3))/2
þ(n) = (n-1)*(n/2)
þ(n)% = þ(n)/(Σ+þ(n))
Σ% = Σ/(Σ+þ(n))
t(1) = (0,5*n^2)+(0,5*n)
t(2) = (1,5*n^2)+(0,5*n)
t(2) = (2,5*n^2)+(0,5*n)
```

Comment: You haven’t even computed your function in your example. Is the denominator $1+2+\dots+3x?$

Comment: I am not sure if my formula is written correctly, but maybe I should have written it out differently? This image here is how it does look on my pc. https://i.imgur.com/Jl6HwFo.png

Comment: So your function is the difference, not the ration of the difference and the sum? That’s certainly not what your original formula in the image said.

Comment: I have removed the formula, hope it will remove some confusion. Ehm.. If you take a sequence of numbers and chop it into 3 equal pieces,  then subtract the third piece from the second piece, you would get the first piece if the sequence is (1,2,3), but for (most?) longer sequences, like (1,2,3,4,5,6) this does not work, that is when I made the function to get the % of difference as shown in the example, written out as ΔΣ (if that would be an appropriate symbol for it, not sure. O.O)

Comment: Well, your percentage difference is strange, because the denominator is $p+\Sigma,$ when it makes more sense to have the denominator $\Sigma.$ $p+\Sigma$ is just $2t(3).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m going to use $p(n)$ rather than your symbol, because I don’t want to keep copying and pasting your symbol, and I don’t know the LaTex name for the symbol. (Also, $n$ rather than $x$ because it appears the the function takes integers, and $x$ implies real values.)

Then $$\begin{align}p(n)&={\sum_{m=2n+1}^{3n} m-\sum_{m=1}^{2n}m}\\
&={\left(2n^2+ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)-n(2n+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{(5n^2+n)-(4n^2+2n)}{2}\\
&=\frac{n^2-n}{2}
\end{align}$$

Then the denominator is, if I understand tour formula, $$\Sigma(n)=\sum_{m=1}^{3n}m=\frac{3n(3n+1)}{2}$$

So, $$\frac{p(n)}{\Sigma(n)}=\frac{n-1}{3(3n+1)}$$

which converges to $\frac19\approx 0.111,$ not your limit.

But one reading of your formula might be:

$$\frac{p(n)}{p(n)+\Sigma(n)}=\frac{n(n-1)}{n(n-1)+3n(3n+1)}=\frac{n-1}{10n+2}$$

Which converges to $\frac1{10}.$

In particular, $$\frac1{10}-\frac{p(n)}{\Sigma(n)+p(n)}=\frac{3}{25n+5}$$

Recall that $0.0999999\dots=0.1=\frac1{10}.$

Comment: Thank you a lot for explaining! Will try to remember. :) I do not yet know why it stops at 0,099.. as explained. I wonder if there is some kind of relation between tridants of a sequence and the number 0.099..